# How to get date object timezone text in french?

Tags: javascript, date

When I use new Date() I get o/p as `Mon Nov 30 2020 16:41:46 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`. Can I get `Eastern Standard Time` in french? I tried with the following, but didn't work. Is there any method to return french text?

```js
  var d = new Date();
  console.log(d);
  console.log(d.toLocaleString("fr-FR"));
```

I need to detect the visitor timezone and display it as Eastern etc.. timezone. Since, my app is in french, is there a way to get the visitor timezone and translate it into french. I know I can do it by using translate service. I am just curious if there is a method that translates the timezone automatically to desired language. Everything is translated with toLocaleString, just the Eastern Standard Time. I can pass options as `const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };`, is there a option for EST.

Comment: I'm confused, `"30/11/2020 à 16:46:02"` looks like French to me, with the day/month/year formatting, the " à ", and the 24 hour time.

Comment: How do you verify it's French time? What's your true example to use as comparison? What time is baguette time ?

Comment: I think OP wants the phrase "Eastern Standard Time" to be whatever the translation is in French, which would require either a hardcoded value, a `fetch()` to a translating API like google translate, or some library.

Comment: Apart from my jest about baguettes, I'd advice OP to [check this small package out](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n) it provides a very decent localization :)

Comment: I need to detect the visitor timezone and display it as Eastern, Pacific etc timezone. Since, my app is in french, is there a way to get the visitor timezone and translate it into french. I know I can do it by using translate service. I am just curious if there is a method that translates the timezone to desired language. Everything is translated with toLocaleString, just the Eastern Standard Time.

Comment: @RobG Sorry, Its a typo. Fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```js
 var d= new Date(); 
 var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month:'long', day: 'numeric' };
  //options.timeZone = "UTC";
  options.timeZoneName = "long";
  console.log(d.toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", options));
```

This prints "lundi 30 novembre 2020 à heure normale d’Europe centrale"

Modify the options to suit your needs :)

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find all the options? I need the option for GMT-0500. Can you help me with this option.

Comment: Formatting using *toLocale\** methods and the Intl object (they are the same) does not provide for such specific formatting. You can try the option `timeZoneName: 'short'`, however where the language specified matches the default host language, you will likely get the timezone name abbreviation and where it doesn't match, either GMT±HH or UTC±HH depending on the language chosen. For a full list of options, see [*MDN Intl.DateTimeFormat constructor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).

Comment: @RobG, So, its based on the language. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: @amar—yes. Unfortunately the term "locale" is used for the BCP47 language tag that can also have extensions for calendar, etc. It really should just have been called culture preferences or similar. Formatting should be based on the [*Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)*](http://cldr.unicode.org), however much is left to implementations. If you want a specific format, better to use [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) then organise the bits yourself.